# Smart Contracts designing for desktop application

Tags: contract-development

Can I use smart contract for my desktop application? Even if I don't need blockchain. If yes, then which platform would you recommend?

Comment: It seems this question is unrelated to Ethereum.

Answer (score 1):

in that case, it would be no longer a smart contract but just a simple desktop application. 
So you can do it with classic approach take an IDE and code your application and after that build it.